# Can you pass return multiple arrays with window.postMessage

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to pass to arrays back to a parent window with window.postMessage?. I have two arrays of data to pass back but can't seam to figure out how to do it. I tried

```
                    window.opener.postMessage(array1+'**'+array2,'*');
```

but on the parent page I can't figure out how to split the arrays , I used.split('**') but that just splits the arrays in two then I can't get the individual data out of those. any help would be greatly appericated.

Comment: `.postMessage([array1, array2], "*")`

Comment: Thanks  Andreas that worked. in the parrent window i just had to  let data1 = event.data[0]    then i can just data1[0]..ect to get the individual numbers out. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with spread operator is realy simple and is a modern javascript:

```
window.opener.postMessage([...array1, ...array2],'*');
```

Comment: This only works if OP doesn't need two separate arrays